# writing a custom message and using it in a different package

Tags: ros, catkin-make, callback, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

first of all, I have gone through these links, so it is not a repeat question:

- http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages
- http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg
- http://answers.ros.org/question/31779/how-to-use-a-message-that-i-made/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/62092/catkin_make-started-failing-to-generate-h-from-msg/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/62707/jenkins-fails-to-build-with-no-such-file-or-directory/

and i tried all of these solutions, but they did not help me.

The question is..

I have created a msg folder in package 'A'. wrote hello.msg in that 'msg' folder. I followed this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg and catkin_make worked fine here.

I now created a new package 'B' , has a node 'helpme.cpp' and in that I have written `#include "A/hello.h"`
and I defined

```
A::hello left,right;
left.myheight = image.rows;
left.mywidth = image.cols;
```

.....in the callback function
and when I do `catkin_make`, it says..

```
/home/krish/architecture_ws/src/rectifier/src/camera_timestamp_node.cpp:276:6: error: ‘const ImageConstPtr’ has no member named ‘mywidth’
/home/krish/architecture_ws/src/rectifier/src/camera_timestamp_node.cpp:277:6: error: ‘const ImageConstPtr’ has no member named ‘myheight’
```

pls tell me what changes should I make in `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` in the packages A and B.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213020/writing-a-custom-message-and-using-it-in-a-different-package/) by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-07**:
Could you please reformat this, I just over read your message definition. The readability is quite horrible.
Like use the code (0101010) Button for your message definition.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-07**:
I've fixed your formatting a bit, because as @cyborg-x1 writes, it was unintelligible before. Please take care of formatting your question properly in the future: it increases your chances of getting answers.

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-07**:
ok, gvdhoorn and cybord-x1, I will take care of formatting from next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this problem because of my programming mistake.
I have given the same variable name to both ImageConstPtr and my own message type.
the problem is solved now
thanks gvdhoorn and cyborg-x1

---

Originally posted by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) with karma: 11 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess there is something wrong with your topic callback rather than catkin not finding it:

/home/krish/architecture_ws/src/rectifier/src/camera_timestamp_node.cpp:276:6: error: **‘const ImageConstPtr’ has no member named ‘mywidth’**

You should use const HelloConstPtr instead of ImageConstPtr. if the name is Hello...

I guess you edited a node using an Image message, right?

Regards

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-07**:
int8 seq_id

std_msgs/Header timestamp

int8 frame_id

float64 myheight

float64 mywidth

int16 step_value

int32[] myimage_data

is my hello.msg

I guess my call back function is fine. it is being called before I introduced my own message type.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-07**:
But if you have have a message called hello.msg you will need the class **hello**ConstPtr in your callback function currently you are using **Image**ConstPtr according to your compiler error. And ImageConstPointer only features width not mywidth. (sensor_msgs)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> /home/krish/architecture_ws/src/rectifier/src/camera_timestamp_node.cpp:276:6: error: ‘const ImageConstPtr’ has no member named ‘mywidth’
> ```

```
/home/krish/architecture_ws/src/rectifier/src/camera_timestamp_node.cpp:277:6: error: ‘const ImageConstPtr’ has no member named ‘myheight’
```

This is a bit of a guess (as we don't have the actualy msg definition), but I'd say that your trying to access the `mywidth` member variable of an `ImageConstPtr` itself, not of the object *it is pointing to*. That probably fails, because the *pointer* will not have that member, only the *pointed to* has it.

To access the field on the pointed to, you'd probably have to dereference the `ImageConstPtr`, which you would do with `my_ptr->mywidth` (which uses the shorthand form of the [dereference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1